# BeautifulSoup, Google Scholar, Authors names, affiliations and citations too

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-scholar

I would like to get all the authors names from Google Scholar. My base url is http://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security
so basically, I look for authors who wrote anything about security.

I wrote some Python script using BeautifulSoup, but (dont know why) the script shows empty lists,
as it did not find any given elements (however, when I look into the page source, I see there `<div class="gsc_1usr_text">` elements).

Heres my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "gsc_1usr_text" })
print mydivs
```

and the output is `[]`, `print "LEN = " + str(len(mydivs))` shows me 0.

Im using **Python 2.7.3** on **Linux Mint 13**.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Interesting! Could you please show me your output? I have only empty lists, don't know why :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "gsc_1usr_text" })
print mydivs
```

Output:

```
[<div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=n-Oret4AAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Adrian Perrig</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">Professor of Computer Science at ETH Zürich, Adjunct Professor of ECE and EPP at CMU</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z inf.ethz.ch</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@inf.ethz.ch</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 40938</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:networking">Networking</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:operating_systems">Operating Systems</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:computer_security">Computer Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:internet_security">Internet Security</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=HvwPRJ0AAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Vern Paxson</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">Professor, EECS, University of California, Berkeley</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z berkeley.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@berkeley.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 39914</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:networking">Networking</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:measurement">Measurement</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=2pW1g5IAAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Mihir Bellare</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">Professor, Department of Computer Science and Engineering, UCSD</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z eng.ucsd.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@eng.ucsd.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 35459</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:cryptography">Cryptography</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:complexity_theory">Complexity Theory</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=FCsdj0YAAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Wenyuan Xu</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">Assistant Profess of Department of Computer Science and Engineering, University of South  …</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 32521</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:wireless_networks">Wireless Networks</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:jamming_defenses">jamming defenses</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:dependable_systems">dependable systems</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=vWTI60AAAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Martin Abadi</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">Principal Scientist, Google, and Professor Emeritus, UC Santa Cruz</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z cs.ucsc.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@cs.ucsc.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 29938</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:programming_languages_and_systems">programming languages and systems</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:specification_and_verification">specification and verification</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=lOZ1vHIAAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Sushil Jajodia</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">University Professor, BDM International Professor, and Director, Center for Secure  …</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z gmu.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@gmu.edu</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 29705</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:privacy">privacy</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:database">database</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:databases">databases</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:distributed_systems">distributed systems</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=Z_enRVYAAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Xiaolan Zhang</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">IBM</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z us.ibm.com</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@us.ibm.com</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 27321</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:virtualization">Virtualization</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:systems">Systems</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=W7YBLlEAAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Jean-Pierre Hubaux</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">Professor, EPFL</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z epfl.ch</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@epfl.ch</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 24738</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:privacy">Privacy</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:networking">Networking</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=WgyDcoUAAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Ross Anderson</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">University of Cambridge</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z cl.cam.ac.uk</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@cl.cam.ac.uk</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 24445</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">Security</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:cryptology">cryptology</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:dependability">dependability</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:technology_policy">technology policy</a> </div></div>, <div class="gsc_1usr_text"><h3 class="gsc_1usr_name"><a href="/citations?user=lsKlsJ8AAAAJ&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2">Heejo Lee</a></h3><div class="gsc_1usr_aff">Professor of Computer Science, Korea University</div><div class="gsc_1usr_eml">Zweryfikowany adres z korea.ac.kr</div><div class="gsc_1usr_emlb">@korea.ac.kr</div><div class="gsc_1usr_cby">Cytowane przez 23596</div><div class="gsc_1usr_int"><a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:network">network</a> <a class="gsc_co_int" href="/citations?view_op=search_authors&amp;hl=pl&amp;oe=Latin2&amp;mauthors=label:security">security</a> </div></div>]
```

Comment: How is that possible? You got all the authors I need! What OS and Python version did you use? Anyway, what should I do to get the same result? (I mean, any result, now it prints only empty lists ...)

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 14.04, python version 2.7 because `print mydivs` won't work in 3+

Comment: So how can I do this? Even `for e in mydivs : print e` does not work, it does not print divs, I have Python 2.7.3

Comment: did you import **`import urllib2`** module?

Comment: Really dont know what causes the issue. Installed Mint 17 on VM, and it seems to work too but I would like to solve this out anyway, here at Mint 13.

Comment: This code works for me. However, if I put this url instead: `http://scholar.google.pl/scholar?q=compressed+differential+heuristic`, then I get error 503. Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

You might send too many requests or Google detected your script as an automatic script.

The first thing you can try to do is to add proxies to your request:

```py
#https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

proxies = {
  'http': os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY') # Or just type your proxy here without os.getenv()
}
```

Or you can make it work by using either `requests-html` or `selenium` to render the whole HTML page without using proxies, but you can still get a CAPTCHA.

Code to make it work(*I tested code locally*):

```py
# If you get an empty array, you get an CAPTCHA from Google.
# Print response to see what cause it.
# Note: code below doesn't do pagination. https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/#pagination

from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security'
response = session.get(url)
# https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/#requests_html.HTML.render
response.html.render(sleep=1)

for author_name in response.html.find('.gs_ai_name'):
    name = author_name.text
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
Johnson Thomas
Martin Abadi
Adrian Perrig
Vern Paxson
Frans Kaashoek
Mihir Bellare
Matei Zaharia
Helen J. Wang
Zhu Han
Sushil Jajodia
```

Alternatively, you can use [Google Scholar Profiles API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-profiles-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a trial of 5,000 searches. A completely free trial is currently under development.

The main difference is you don't have to think about solving a CAPTCHA or experience a slow scraping process because of the rendering page or stress PC with multiple instances e.g. using `selenium`

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google_scholar_profiles",
  "hl": "en",
  "mauthors": "label:security",
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for author_name in results['profiles']:
    name = author_name['name']
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
Johnson Thomas
Martin Abadi
Adrian Perrig
Vern Paxson
Frans Kaashoek
Mihir Bellare
Matei Zaharia
Helen J. Wang
Zhu Han
Sushil Jajodia
```

Part of the JSON output:

```json
"profiles": [
  {
    "name": "Johnson Thomas",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=eKLr0EgAAAAJ",
    "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?author_id=eKLr0EgAAAAJ&engine=google_scholar_author&hl=en",
    "author_id": "eKLr0EgAAAAJ",
    "affiliations": "Professor of Computer Science, Oklahoma State University",
    "email": "Verified email at cs.okstate.edu",
    "cited_by": 150263,
    "interests": [
      {
        "title": "Security",
        "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_scholar_profiles&hl=en&mauthors=label%3Asecurity",
        "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:security"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.